# Prototype.js, calling invoke observe click, trying to get the element clicked. Confusion about scope

Tags: javascript, scope, prototypejs, this

Is there a way, using 'invoke', with 'observe', and 'click' as arguments, to access the item that 'invoke' is currently iterating through?

I am doing this:

1.

```
$$('.item').invoke('observe', 'click', function(event) {
    // I want to access the .item that was clicked in here
});
```

I can do

2.

```
$$('.item').first().observe('click', function(node) {
    // I can access the .item right here with 'node'
})
```

I can even do

3.

```
    $$(".item").each(function(node) {
      node.observe('click', function(event) {
        // use 'node' here for the .item clicked
    });
```

But I want to know if there is a way to do #1 (the shorthand way), while still accessing the element that was clicked.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer.

What I was looking for was [Event.element(event)](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/element/), which returns the element in which the event was called.

I also should note that in order to use prototype methods on event.element, you need to wrap it in the prototype selector like this:

```
var element = $(Event.element(event))
```

Comment: Try using `this` inside the closure - it should be the extended element that the event happened on - you can also use `event.findElement()` which will return the extended element

Comment: No, actually 'this' inside the invoke statement points to the 'event' that was fired and not the 'element' it was fired in, which isn't what I needed.

Comment: +1 to the reply as this would still be a reserved keyword that javascript would interpret to mean 'this' in terms of lexical scoping.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Event.on](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) in place of Event.observe:

```
$$('.item').invoke('on', 'click', '.item', function(event, el) {
    // el is the '.item' element
});
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
<div id="item-container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>

$('item-container').on('click', '.item', function(event, el) {
    // el is the '.item' element
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
});
```

This is sweet since you're setting up only a single event handler on #item-container which lets you add/remove .item children without having to worry about registering/unregistering event handlers. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

my funcion good:

```
*Event.observe(document, 'click', respondToClick);
function respondToClick(e) {                    
    var el = e.element();
    var del = el.hasClassName('classIdDiv');
    var id = el.identify();
    if(del == true){
        Function_personal(id);
        return;
    }
}*
```